# Explantation for const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String]

Tags: objective-c, ios7

What does this line of code do ?

```
const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String]
```

This line is used while fetching the SQLite database details.

Thanks

Comment: And what's the rest of the code? Maybe be cause one parameters has to be a `char *`? Since it may be in C inside the library, and not necessarily in Objective-C with the use of a `NSString` object?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [NSString Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSString/UTF8String), `UTF8String` returns:

> A null-terminated UTF8 representation of the string. (read-only)

So in your case it gives you an UTF8 representation of your database path.